# What are some easy differentiable and bounded curves on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: derivatives, examples-counterexamples, curves

For instance, you have the circle:

$$ x^2 + y^2 = 1$$
It is differentiable on both $x$ and $y$ and it describes a bounded set.

Now you could pick an easier equation, like $x+y=1$, which is linear instead of quadratic. However it does not describe a bounded set...

It has to be only one an differentiable equation, so stuff like $||(x,y)||_\infty = 1$ or $\{x+y=1, x \geq 0, y \geq 0\}$ don't count. So what are some easy equations differentiable on both $x$ and $y$ that describe a bounded set? Easy as in involving only simple functions of $x$ and $y$. I'd rather they be about as easy as the actual circle, or preferably easier

Comment: Do you find ellipses easy enough? For example $$x^2 + axy + y^2=1$$ where $a \in (-2;2)$ is a family of ellipses

Comment: You can also use parametric equations:  $x =\cos^3 \theta, y = \sin^3 \theta$, $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$